# No output while executing SQL query in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I run the below code in Oracle SQL, it shows output. But when I execute it through PreparedStatement in Java, there's no output in ResultSet.

```
select p.table_name, 'is parent of ' rel, c.table_name
from   all_constraints p
join   all_constraints c on c.r_constraint_name = p.constraint_name
                         and c.r_owner = p.owner
where p.table_name = '<table-name>'    
union all
select c.table_name, 'is child of ' rel, p.table_name
from   all_constraints p
join   all_constraints c on c.r_constraint_name = p.constraint_name
                         and c.r_owner = p.owner
where c.table_name = '<table-name>'    ;
```

Comment: Please show your java code (edit your question)

Comment: can you share your java code ?

Comment: Remove the semi-colon from the end? Apart from that you need to post the java code you are using and the error message you are receiving. (Please, edit your question rather than adding code in comments.)

Comment: PreparesStatement ps= conn.prepareStatement(above sql code);

Comment: Are you connected as the same user, or at least as a user with privileges to see the same metadata?

Comment: Yes I have removed the end semicolon

Comment: Has the data been committed?

Comment: @MT0 yes bro.....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Actually  all_constraints table can be accessed only with SYSDBA privileges. So, I gave SYSDBA privilege and executed. It worked fine.

Thank You for all your responses. Cheers..